# Как удалить определенное число элементов из Dictionary?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Есть коллекция, типа

```
Dictionary<String, int>
```

В некий момент из нее надо удалить первые *X* элементов. (Точнее, идет цикл, работающий с первыми X элементами, после чего их надо выкинуть из коллекции)

Как это можно сделать? Насколько я знаю, из Dictionary элементы можно удалять только по отдельности (Remove) либо все вместе (Clear). Ничего, вроде List.RemoveAll(statement) для Dictionary нет. Была мысль удалять элементы прямо после работы с ними в цикле:

```
 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in items)
 {
    // что-то делаем
    items.Remove(item.Key);
 }
```

Но, по-моему, удалять элементы из коллекции прямо по ходу цикла по ней же - это плохая идея.

Comment: Гениально же )). @ShockWave, конвертните в ответ, что ли. Приму. Что-то меня стало подозрительно часто клинить на простых вещах.

Comment: Не гонюсь за рейтингом, забирайте даром :)

Comment: Кстати, заклин на простых вещах, это признак переработки, или того что вы тратите на программирование меньше 2 часов в сутки

Comment: @Olter

- Отмечу, что фраза "первые `X` элементов" для `IDictionary<T, U>` - это адовая жесть. Мало того, что `IDictionary<,>` может не гарантировать одинакового порядка при двух разных запусках `foreach` (что, в общем, скорее исключение, чем правило), так еще и любое добавление элемента в `IDictionary<,>` может изменить порядок обхода этой коллекции.

- Понятно, что, в связи с вышенаписанным, фраза "первые `X` элементов" представляется довольно странной.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать - автор указал что первые Х элементов идут в контексте текущего for-each итерирования. Его логически-синтаксическая ошибка воспринята вами в стиле работы самой программы. Процесс написания этой программы, адово жестко катастрофически отличается от процесса её исполнения. Спасибо.

Comment: Это не просто плохая идея, Вам среда выполнения не даст так сделать, бросив исключение.

Comment: в той секвенции что я предложил, не будет ошибок
главное не теребить словарь до удалений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cоздать список ключей, и удалить в следующем цикле.

Answer (score -2):

Не используй foreach, используй for:

```
for(int i=0; i < items.length; i++){
   if(условие){
       //удаляем...
       i--; //делаем шаг назад так как количество элементов уменьшилось
   }
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы посмотреть пример "условия" для данного подхода.